# Last max of a nested list?

Tags: list, nested, prolog, max, nested-lists

max1([X], X).

max2([X], X).

maxx([H,H1,H2|T],M) :-

```
max1(H2,Max),
M is Max.
```

maxx([H,H1,H2|T], M) :-

```
max2(H2, Max),
M is Max.
```

max1([H|T],MaxT):-

```
max1(T, MaxT),
H > MaxT.
```

max2([H|T], MaxT) :-

```
max2(T, MaxT),
H =< MaxT.
```

****this is my code.it finds only if you put 3 nested lists.how i can make it to find  n nested lists ****

Comment: What have you tried? Also, please try formatting your question properly and using a real question title. If you put less than three seconds into asking for help, it makes us want to put less than three seconds into helping you.

Comment: First isolate the last list, then find the max value of that one list.

Comment: yeah i couldnt put a title i was writing titles many of them but it dosnt accept anything .  i am begginer.  i didnt try anything actualy i know how to find max of a list easily but i cant find the max of the last list of lists (nested list) . i was hoping for solution from someone who knows. sorry if something is weird in my topic  i am new :)

Comment: find_max_of_last([X], X).

find_max_of_last([H|T], M) :-

    
 find_max_of_last(T, MaxT),
 H > MaxT,
 M = H.
find_max_of_last([H|T], M) :-

 find_max_of_last(T, MaxT),
 H =< MaxT,
 M = MaxT.

Comment: Edit your question and put your code there. It's not very clear in a comment and many readers will miss it.